# Listening to BLE Device continuously, even while app in background/suspended state

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I`m developing an app which needs to listen to a BLE device all the time, save the data to a core data and send it to a cloud API.
I declared a required background mode for the app with "App communicates using CoreBluetooth' and the app does run and save and send data for a while. but after a couple of minutes the process get terminated by the OS and I can't manage to save and send data.
Every sample is 32 bytes and we are receiving packets continuously

This Is the function which is being called every time we receive an update for the characteristic.

```
            let byteArray = [UInt8](value)
            if self.isFirstTime{
                print("First Time BLE Incoming Called")
                print(byteArray.count)
                self.DataBuffer = self.DataBuffer + Array(byteArray[32...byteArray.count-1]) //Ignore the first 32 bytes
                self.PickedDeviceId = Int(self.DataBuffer[DeviceIDByteIndex])
                if self.PickedDeviceId != -1{
                    self.isFirstTime = false
                }
                print("Picked Device ID ", self.PickedDeviceId)
                let myConcurrentQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "ConcurrentQueue",
                                                      qos: .background,
                                                      attributes: .concurrent,
                                                      autoreleaseFrequency: .workItem,
                                                      target: nil)
                myConcurrentQueue.async {
                    var dataStructure:DataStructure!
                    while true{
                        self.serialQueue.sync {
                            if (self.DataBuffer.count>31){
                                print("Number of samples taken ", self.dataBuffer.count)
                                dataStructure = DataStructure.createFromByteArray(Array(self.DataBuffer[0..<32]))
self.DataBuffer.removeSubrange(0..<32)
if(dataStructure != nil && dataStructure.DeviceID == self.PickedDeviceId){

self.CHState = dataStructure.PelStatus
                                    self.processDataStructure(dataStructure!)
                                    self.cloudManager.addDSToSend(datastructure: dataStructure!)
                                    if(self.isCalibrated()){
                                        self.checkIfNotifyAlarm(dataStructure: dataStructure)
                                    }
                                    print("Number of samples processed ", self.dataBuffer.count)
                                }
                                else{///Sometimes we receive junk data so we need to filter it
                                    print("Faulty data, recovering by Removing Bytes ")
                                    if(self.DataBuffer.count > 24){
                                        while(Int(self.DataBuffer[DeviceIDByteIndex]) != self.PickedDeviceId){
                                        self.DataBuffer.removeFirst()
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        self.DataBuffer.removeAll()
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return
            }
            self.serialQueue.sync {
                print("Entering Adding ",String(byteArray.count)," bytes")
                self.DataBuffer = self.DataBuffer + byteArray
                print("Number of bytes available ",self.DataBuffer.count)
            }
            print("Finished Adding bytes")

    }'''
```

Comment: You can't have a `while true` loop. Even in the foreground, this is a bad idea. You need your peripheral to `notify` when there is new data and for your app to enable notifications on the relevant characteristic. This will call your your `didUpdateCharacteristic`delegate method where you can process the new data

Comment: But the notify is called when there is more than 1 sample to process, and I need all them

Comment: You still don't need a `while true`. Put the samples in a queue.  Process the queue. Suspend until the next sample arrives. I haven't looked closely at your code but you will need to be sure you access your arrays in a thread safe manner.

Comment: Thanks Paul! Your comment was very helpful

Comment: Can you give me a code example for managing a thread safe array?

Comment: A common technique is to use `sync` to dispatch array updates onto a dedicated queue